# Iteración con append, detectar selected con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches no se muy bien como ejecutar esto, para que en mi iteración de values que hago con append, detectar con una variable global cual está seleccionado.

**Este es mi append**

```
$('#zonasGuardaTicket').append('<option value="'+ mesas[i].id +'">'+ mesas[i].mesa +' - ('+ posicion +')</option>');
```

Luego tengo una variable global que se llama `mesaID`.

Quiero hacer algo como esto, que habitualmente hago en php:

```
{{ ( $mesa->id== $local->mesaID) ? 'selected' : '' }}
```

Es esto posible con jquery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var messageId = "3";
  var options = {
    1: "opción 1",
    2: "opción 2",
    3: "opción 3",
    4: "opción 4",
    5: "opción 5",
    6: "opción 6"
  }; 
  
  $.each(options,function(key,value){
    $("#selector").append('<option value="'+key+'"'+ (key == messageId ? 'selected' : '')+'>'+value+'</option>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>Si quieres que se seleccione al indicar una opción, modifica la variable messageId. Se puede establecer los números comprendidos del 1 al 6.</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
<select id="selector" class ="form-select" aria-label="Selecciona una opción">
<option selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Para acceder a la opción seleccionada por el usuario a partir de un selector, puedes usar los selectores de Jquery. En este código que te indico, se selecciona las opción seleccionada por el usuario para el elemento select con id **zonasGuardaTicket**.

```
 $('#zonasGuardaTicket>option:selected')
```

Comment: ¿Cómo funciona este código?, ¿Qué es lo que hace?, ¿Cómo resuelve el problema de OP?. Es mejor dar respuestas explicando siempre el código que se propone para que más usuarios puedan comprenderla. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM tienes toda la razón. Modificada la respuesta.

Comment: Hola @rubenchus perdona la tardanza pero me tube que poner a otras cosas, pero como comparo ahí con mi variable `mesaID` ??

Comment: Hola @Miguel te he dejado un ejemplo de lo que me pides. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Funciona perfecto @rubenchus muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas utilizar el atributo `selectedIndex` para ubicar la posición de la opción seleccionada dentro del conjunto de opciones, al cual accedes a través del atributo `options`.

```
miSelectBox.options[miSelectBox.selectedIndex]
```

Una vez que ya tienes eso, puedes acceder a todos los atributos y valores de dicha opción.

Comment: Hola @Alexis88 no comprendo bien, y como utilizo mi variable global ahí?

Comment: Según veo en el ejemplo en PHP, si dos determinados valores son iguales, asignas el valor `selected` a lo que me imagino es un `<opción>`. Con lo que te indiqué, directamente detectas la opción que se encuentra seleccionada, algo que con PHP no se puede hacer directamente porque no es un lenguaje del lado del cliente. Si eso no es lo que buscas, por favor, explica un poco mejor lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola @Alexis88 . Lo que busco es que en ese select vienen distintos valores, en una variable global guardo yo la id del selector que quiero que este como selected, me comprendes algo mejor así?

Comment: Si la ID ya la tienes de forma predeterminada, entonces puedes recorrer el listado de opciones desde `miSelectBox.options`, en donde `miSelectBox` es el `<select>`, y en cada iteración del bucle comparar el valor predeterminado del ID con la propiedad `value` de cada `<option>`. Una vez que identifiques la opción, solo te queda asignarle el valor `true` a la propiedad `selected`.